# Trying to create lotto game, having problems with execution and compilation

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

im trying to set up a lottery game that asks for input from the user 3 times and compares this to numbers drawn by the random array. if any of these user numbers match a number in the array, the program should print out the numbers that matched.

ive tried to use while loops in my main function to control the flow but im still having issues with compilation

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "array.h"

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;
const int sizeofArray = 20;

void assign(int wins[], int sizeofArray);
void draw(int sizeofArray, int wins[]);
bool check(int num1, int wins[], int sizeofArray);
void entry(int& userNum);
void printOut(int wins[], int num);


int main() {

    srand(time(nullptr));
    int user[sizeofArray];
    cout << "Good luck with this weeks lotto drawing!" << endl;
    int wins[sizeofArray];

    assign(wins, sizeofArray);
    draw(sizeofArray, wins);
    int userInput;
    entry(userInput);

   bool win = check(userInput, wins, sizeofArray);
    if (win)
        cout << "you have won!" << endl;
    printOut(wins, sizeofArray);

}


void assign(int wins[], int sizeofArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeofArray; ++i)
        wins[i] = 0;
}
void draw(int sizeofArray, int wins[]) {
    int number = 0;
    while (number < sizeofArray) {
        int number = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if (!check(number, wins, sizeofArray)) {
            wins[number] = number;
            number++;
        }
    }
}
bool check(int num1, int wins[], int sizeofArray) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeofArray; j++) {
        if (wins[j] == num1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
void entry(int& userNum) {
    int j;
    cout << "Enter your lottery number guess: ";
    cin >> userNum;
    cout << "Your number was " << userNum << endl;
}
void printOut(int wins[], int num) {
    cout << "Winning numbers in lottery are" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
        cout << wins[j] << " ";
    }
}

i
```

Comment: If you get compiler errors, please copy and paste them here.

Comment: well I shouldn't say compiler errors, but it seems to be looping infinitely

Comment: does `draw` loop inifinetly?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to determine where the infinite loop is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Your draw method is going to loop infinitely since you declared the condition variable twice which causes the ++ operator to be applied on the wrong variable

```
void draw(int sizeofArray, int wins[]) {
    int number = 0; // <--- HERE
    while (number < sizeofArray) {
        int number = rand() % 100 + 1; // <--- AND HERE
        if (!check(number, wins, sizeofArray)) {
            wins[number] = number;
            number++; //This will increase the inner variable number not the outer one
        }
    }
}
```

to fix it just change the name of your variable

```
void draw(int sizeofArray, int wins[]) {
    int counter = 0; <---
    while (counter < sizeofArray) { <---
        int number = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if (!check(number, wins, sizeofArray)) {
            wins[number] = number;
            counter++; <---
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at `draw()`:

```
void draw(int sizeofArray, int wins[]) {
    int number = 0; //First variable of name number
    while (number < sizeofArray) {
        //new variable with name number is introduced, it shadows the first one  
        int number = rand() % 100 + 1; //<-----------------------+
        if (!check(number, wins, sizeofArray)) {              // |
            wins[number] = number;                            // |
            number++; //Here you actually increase this variable-+
        }
    }
}
```

So called shadowing occurs here and the outer `int number` is never modified inside the loop. Just rename one of them and you should be fine.

If you want to read more about this, take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).